# WPF XAML listview - turn a visually shown '1' in a cell into a visually show word in the same cell at displaytime

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview

I've got a listview displaying this (more or less):

```
--------------------------------------------------------
| Rule no. | Rule Type | Rule Name | Priority | Active |
--------------------------------------------------------
|   1      |     1     |  My Rule  |    1     |   1    |
--------------------------------------------------------
```

using this XAML:

```
<ListView.View>
    <GridView>
        <GridViewColumn Header="Rule No" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=RuleNo}" Width="150" />
        <GridViewColumn Header="Rule Type" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=RuleTypeNo}" Width="75">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=RuleTypeNo}" Value="1">   
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </DataTemplate.Triggers>        
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn>
        <GridViewColumn Header="Rule Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=RuleName}" Width="430"/>
        <GridViewColumn Header="Priority" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=RulePriority}" Width="50"/>
        <GridViewColumn Header="Active" Width="50">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox Visibility="Visible" Name="chkActive" IsChecked="{Binding RuleActive}">
                        <TextBlock Text=" "/>
                    </CheckBox>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn>
    </GridView>
</ListView.View>
```

All I want to do is for the RuleTypeNo column change the data value

1

into the word

App

and the value

2

into the word

Dial

visually at runtime in the listview cell. E. g. if the column contains a 1, show a word, if the column contains a 2, show another word.

This appears almost impossible, I've spent about 9 hours straight on this now. As you can see I attempted to use a datatrigger to do this, but it apparently never fires. I've tried various setters, but I either cannot get the setter to be be valid markup, or nothing happens when the listview displays - e. g. the trigger is apparently ignored.

What am I doing wrong? I've searched extensively, but nobody appears to want to interpret  actual data in a cell via-trigger to show it in another form - turn a number into a word - everybody wants to change colors, font etc. - I do not want to change the style, I want to change the displayed value in the cell for the Rule Type Number...

How can I change a visually displayed value in a cell into another displayed value in the same cell in an XAML listview? I just want to interpret a '1' into "App" and a '2' into "Dial", visually.

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a [ValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to change the value.

Include the converter in the Resources section of your XAML with:

```
<src:MyConverter x:Key="myConverter"/>
```

And then adjust your binding:

```
<GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=RuleNo,
                                      Converter={StaticResource myConverter}}}"/>
```

The converter would look something like:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(int), typeof(String))]
public class MyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value,
                          Type targetType,
                          object parameter,
                          CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int number = (int)value;
        if (number == 1)
            return "App";
        if (number == 2)
            return "Dial";
        ...
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value,
                              Type targetType,
                              object parameter,
                              CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

That said, my personal preference would be to expose a new property called e.g. RuleTypeDescription on the thing you're binding too; instead of binding to the number.

EDIT

If you want to do it with triggers, you can do something like:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Thingy">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type WpfTests:Item}">
            <TextBlock>
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyNumber}" Value="1">
                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="One"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyNumber}" Value="2">
                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="Two"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Note that we aren't setting DisplayMemberBinding or binding to the Text attribute in the TextBlock element.

Comment: Hi Scroog1

Thanks, that cracked it!

Had to add a `xmlns:src="clr-namespace:VeriDialClient.uihelper"` in `<window>` tag which referred to the Visual Studio project folder in which the converter code was  was located, then in `<Window.Resources>` added the `<src:` line, and modified the gridviewcolumn statement. Thank you VERY much for the help!